# Python: shape of a matrix and imshow()

Tags: python, arrays, multidimensional-array, numpy, matplotlib

I have a 3-D array ar.

```
print shape(ar)  # --> (81, 81, 256)
```

I want to plot this array.

```
fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(111)
for i in arange(256):
    im1 = ax1.imshow(ar[:][:][i])
    plt.draw()
    print i
```

I get this error-message:

```
    im1 = ax1.imshow(ar[:][:][i])
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Why do I get this strange message? The graph has the size 81 x 256 and not like expected 81 x 81. But why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do:

```
ar[:,:,i]
```

The syntax `ar[:]` makes a copy of `ar` (slices all its elements), so `ar[:][:][i]` is semantically equivalent to `ar[i]`. This is an 81*256 matrix, since ndarrays are nested lists.

Comment: then I get an other error: TypeError: list indices must be integers, not tuple

Comment: @kame: Are you not using numpy here? If not, you should be. Specifically, I think `ar` is a list of lists of lists instead of a numpy array. You can cast it to an array with `ar = np.array( ar )`.